# JQuery: Get forms with at least one input (textfield) filled

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can't figure out why my approach doesn't work.

I have a set of forms and I want to show only those with at least one input filled. Each form has 3 text inputs.

```
       $('.odovzdavajuci_form').each(function (i) {
            if ($(this).find('input[value!=""]').length>0){
                console.log($(this).find('input[value!=""]').length)
                $(this).show();
            }
        });
```

The problem is that it shows all forms including those with zero filled inputs. Console logs number 3 for every form.

Comment: Why would I do that? I want to get all filled, not empty.

Comment: I just realized that. My bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method

> Reduce the set of matched elements to those that match the selector or pass the function's test.

```
$('.odovzdavajuci_form').filter(function (i) {
    return $(this).find('input').filter(function () {
        return $(this).val().trim().length > 0
    }).length > 0
}).show();
```